# What do I do to fix this error I'm getting after making my python program into an executable for Windows?

Tags: python, pyqt6

I'm getting this error when I try to pull up my program after using pyinstaller. It won't open because of this error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgHRx.png

I made this program in python instead of the C# or C++ languages because I only know Java and Python. Any suggestions help.
If you can't load the image, I'll summarize it below without giving unnecessary details.

- Error loading Python DLL
- 'Filepath...\build\main\python310.dll'.
- LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found

How would I go about remedying this?

Comment: Sorry but that's hardly helpful, you need to provide actually *necessary* details about your problem. For instance, *how* did you create the executable?

Comment: It's got something to do with PyInstaller. What switches did you use to create your app? It might be caused by upx. Try adding `--noupx`.

Comment: I used Pyinstaller, musicamante.